# Using PHP to validate range slider

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple range slider that allows a user to select an age

```
<div>
 <label for="age">Age: </label><label id="ageOutput"></label><br><br>
 <input type="range" id="age" name="vol" min="0" max="99" value="16">
 <br>
 <span class="error">* <?php echo $ageErr;?></span>
</div>
```

And I use JavaScript update a label with the value of the slider

```
<script>
 var slider = document.getElementById("age");
 var output = document.getElementById("ageOutput");
 output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

 slider.oninput = function() {
 output.innerHTML = this.value;
 }
</script>
```

I'm trying to use PHP to check the value of the slider and validate whether it's between 16 and 90 but I keep getting an error that "age" doesn't exist.

This is the PHP:

```
if (($_POST["age"]) < 16 || ($_POST["age"]) > 90)
    {
      $ageErr = "Customers must be aged 16-90";
    } 
    else 
    {
      $rangeSlider = test_input($_POST["ageOutput"]);
    }
```

Not really sure where to go from here because this method has been working for other values in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make change some portion in HTML Code.

```
<input type="range" id="age" name="vol" min="0" max="99" value="16">
```

hear you have to replace `name="vol"` to `name="age"`.
I think after this kind of change in code your code works fine.

Comment: if these things do not work fine I have another way to write code.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, the second solution is you have to make a hidden input field.
when you change in range javascript code automatically change the hidden input value.

```
<div>
 <label for="age">Age: </label><label id="ageOutput"></label><br><br>
 <input type="range" id="age" name="vol" min="0" max="99" value="16">
 <input type="hidden" id="setage" name="age"/>
 <br>
 <span class="error">* <?php echo $ageErr;?></span>
</div>
```

Hear is you js code:

```
<script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("age");
     var output = document.getElementById("ageOutput");
     var setage = document.getElementById("setage");
     output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value
     setage.value=slider.value;
     
     slider.oninput = function() {
      output.innerHTML = this.value;
      setage.value = this.value;
     }
</script>
```